# Can there be any avatar(s) of God apart from those mentioned in the scriptures

Tags: gods, avatars, brahman, ishwara

Can there be any avatar of God apart from those mentioned in the scriptures as Sri Krishna said that whenever there is a decline of Dharma he takes birth and also that there are infinite avatars. Pls clarify this